# Why isn't Date.now() executing as I expected?

Tags: javascript

```js
function sleep(callback, delay) {
  const delayUntil = Date.now() + delay;

  while (Date.now() < delayUntil) {
    callback();
  }
}

function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}

function bar() {
  console.log('bar');
}

sleep(foo, 3 * 1000);
bar();
```

I expected `bar` to execute after 3 sec

But it actually took about 50 sec

[image]

please, let me know why this happened

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet and it seems to take about 3 seconds to print `bar`...

Comment: Froze your own browser by printing hundreds of thousands of console messages, I expect. (They’re asynchronous and have features like the duplicate counter you see in the screenshot, so they’re a bit heavier than you might imagine.)

Comment: @Ry- You were right. I tested it with VS Code again, it took a almost 3 sec (maybe including the executing time of foo). thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `date.now()` will be less than delaytime so it will return call back instantly. If you put the call back after the while it should execute after 3 seconds.

EDIT. Miss read your looking for just bar. there will be a delay because the amount of `console.log()` your writing so its taking longer to process hence the delay before returning bar.

```html
<script>
function sleep(callback, delay) {
  const delayUntil = Date.now() + delay;
  while (Date.now() < delayUntil) {}
  return callback();
}

function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}

function bar() {
  console.log('bar');
}

sleep(foo, 3 * 1000);
bar();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to freeze your or any of your clients' computer(s) you should maybe try something like the following:

```js
function sleep(before,after, delay) {
  setTimeout(after,delay);
  before()
}
sleep(foo,bar,3000)

function foo(){console.log("Please wait...")}
function bar(){console.log("Thank you!")}
```

Comment: I was testing because I was curious about the difference between sync and async.
Thanks for letting me know!